# How to revert the new Windows 10 search icon?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-search

Back in May somewhere, all my laptops automatically updated Windows 10. I immediately got disgusted by the look of the new search icon on my taskbar:

[image]

I can't stand the look and size of this icon, it does not follow any Windows 10 UI guides and isn't even inside the grid which all other icons are put in. The lines are no longer 1 pixel in size, and it just looks like something created while working on Windows 10's Sun Valley overhaul which never got fully finished and is now just being released in small parts making Windows 10 a huge mess of different user interfaces.

Does anybody know how to revert this change? It got pushed out in a 700MB update and I am not willing to uninstall this update everywhere. I want something like a registry tweak that can change the glyph back to what it was originally:

[image]

Even after a while I just can't get used to how bad this icon looks, it's rather outrageous some dev at Microsoft saw this and thought it was okay to push this out to millions of people. I don't want to mess with the OS files, I prefer to know of a setting or registry option that can change this.

Comment: I am leaving this website after seeing how non-helpful and toxic the users here are. I was just asking for help...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Right click on the Windows 10 Task Bar and select Task Bar settings.

See Use Small Taskbar Icons and enable that.

The Task Bar will get smaller.

I am not sure why you think Windows standards are being contravened.  Windows 11 has the larger task bar and does not natively permit you to change it.

Comment: Small taksbar icons does not make the icon look normal. It's still bold and far too large. I am seeking for a method to get the icon that was made specifically for Windows 10. The new search icon looks like some kind of early version of Windows 11/Sun Valley UI. It does not fit in Windows 10 and is very disturbing, especially since it's in plain sight. Also in the search box, the normal icon is used, so it's either way a big mix of different UI elements. This icon has been bothering me for months and is way too eye-catching because it doesn't fit in with the other glyphs.

Comment: What I posted is all you can do natively with the newest version of Windows 10. It is changing. The small width task bar is roughly what it used to be.

Comment: I don't think that's true, I have actually found a registry setting for the Search Glyph, and it's value is set to 2, but I can't change it since it sets itself back to 2 automatically. This leads me to believe there is a way to change this but nobody has yet figured out how.

Comment: That is because (as I read somewhere)  Windows 10 is trying to be more like Windows 11 to ease the transition forward.

Comment: @Foxyz: Why not share the path of the registry value???